# If includes "test" between two specific characters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Basically I am trying to setup different auto-replies based on the content of the email body. Below is my current code... In this case, I am trying to set it up so that if an email was sent with the body "test" it will auto-reply with "This is my test". However, I did a print of msg to find out that the body of the email contained a lot more than just "test":

```
<https://voice.google.com>
test
YOUR ACCOUNT <https://voice.google.com> HELP CENTER
<https://support.google.com/voice#topic=1707989> HELP FORUM
<https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/voice>
This email was sent to you because you indicated that you'd like to receive
email notifications for text messages. If you don't want to receive such
emails in the future, please update your email notification settings
<https://voice.google.com/settings#messaging>.
Google LLC
1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy
Mountain View CA 94043 USA
```

The text around "test" will always be the same. The below code works.... however, I would like to specify that it must include "test" between "google.com>" and "YOUR". I've tried a few different things with no luck...

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
function autoReplier() 
{var labelObj = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('autoreply');
var gmailThreads;
var messages;
var sender;for (var gg = 0; gg < labelObj.getUnreadCount(); 
gg++) {
gmailThreads = labelObj.getThreads()[gg];
messages = gmailThreads.getMessages();
for (var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii++) 
  {if (messages[ii].isUnread()){msg = 
messages[ii].getPlainBody();
    if(msg.includes(`test`)) {
        sender = 
messages[ii].getFrom();MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "This is my test");                                                                     
        messages[ii].markRead();
        messages[ii].moveToTrash();
    } else {
    sender = 
messages[ii].getFrom();MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "Sorry, your keyword was not 
recognized");                                                                         
        messages[ii].markRead();
        messages[ii].moveToTrash();
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

I tried to replicate your problem and I think I did.

You could use a regular expression to achieve your goal but this solution is simpler and it worked for me so I hope it will do for you.

- Split `msg` by empty spaces and given the structure of your email, you can check for this:

  ```
  msg.split(' ')[0] == '<https://voice.google.com>\r\ntest\r\nYOUR'
  ```
- I also formatted your code because it is indeed very confusing.

### Solution:

```
function autoReplier() {
  var labelObj = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('autoreply');
  var gmailThreads;
  var messages;
  var sender;
  for (var gg = 0; gg < labelObj.getUnreadCount(); gg++) {
     gmailThreads = labelObj.getThreads()[gg];
     messages = gmailThreads.getMessages();
     for (var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii++){
        if (messages[ii].isUnread()){
           var msg = messages[ii].getPlainBody();
           var check = msg.split(' ')[0] == '<https://voice.google.com>\r\ntest\r\nYOUR';
           if(check) {
              sender = messages[ii].getFrom();
              MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "This is my test");                                                                     
              messages[ii].markRead();
              messages[ii].moveToTrash();
           } 
           else {
              sender = messages[ii].getFrom();
              MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "Sorry, your keyword was not recognized");                                                                         
              messages[ii].markRead();
              messages[ii].moveToTrash();
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this... I appreciate your help. However, with this I am still getting the same problem... I ran logger.log for both msg and check. msg is still the same as before, and check was false. Any ideas why it would return false for me and not you?